# Codable or JSONSerialization - Need to get some javascript wrapped text off a webpage

Tags: ios, swift

Beginner here - I am trying to figure out what to google for tutorials to help me to do this: I need to get some text off a webpage that is in json script and print it into a textview.

When I look at the view-source of the webpage - http://www.sikhnet.com/hukam - here's the big block of javascript that I see with tag of what I need highlighted in orange:

[image]

I have read some posts that say that as of Swift4, json parsing is now native to Swift via Codable. I have also read about JSONSerialization. But I don't know which is better suited to accomplishing my end goal - print the text from this tag to a textview ? Which one should I use here?

I also have a < p> tag on this webpage that I'd like to print as the title of my textviewcontroller. Can Codable/JSONSerialization also help me do that?

Comment: Some issues to remember: javascript is not json, although they are closely related, and javascript embedded in html is certainly not json.  You'll need to find another way to strip the javascript (really the JSON portion) out of the web page, probably based on regex or some other mechanism.  You may need to massage the javascript into JSON (particularly, javascript tags don't need to be quoted, json tags do)

Comment: Once you actually have JSON, then either `Codable` or `JSONSerialization` can be used to actually parse that JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting into the domain of web scrapers, people who extract info from web pages in ways that the authors did not think of.

Your problem is that the `shabad_lines` is a property of a JSON object inside a line of Javascript code embedded in a HTML document. See how many hoops you have to jump through to get it? `Codable` is no help here. If you think "let's do that with regex", you add yet another problem for yourself!

Let's analyze the Javascript code:

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { ... })
```

This means the page is adding properties to the `Drupal.setings` object. How about getting it back from that object? Open the debug console in Safari or Chrome and type this:

```
Drupal.settings.hukam.shabad_lines.gurmukhi
```

And we are getting all 8 lines of shabad! Couple that with the fact that `WKWebView` allows you to execute Javascript from a webpage and some idea should be bubbling in your mind.

---

## The Solution

It is conceptually simple: load the page, run a line of Javascript, send the result back to Swift. If you are not familiar with `WKWebView` and how things are related, it can look like a mystery. The nesting goes like this:

- The `WKWebView` has a `WKWebViewConfiguration`, which has a `WKUserContentController`, which has a `WKUserScript`.
- Use the `WKWebView` to load the webpage
- Use the `WkUserScript` to execute the Javascript and send a message back to Swift
- Use the `WKUserContentController` to define message handlers, i.e. channels on which Javascript communicates with Swift.

Putting everything together:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a request to load the page
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.sikhnet.com/hukam")!)

        // Create the webview and load the URL
        webView = createWebView()
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func createWebView() -> WKWebView {
        // This is the Javascript to execute you receive back `shabad_lines`
        // property of `Drupal.settings`.
        //
        // Note the `window.webkit.messageHandlers.shabad.postMessage(...)` call:
        // this is how you send a message from Javascript back to Swift. `shabad`
        // is a custom message handler that we will define below. Later, when we
        // get the message back, we will check that it did come from the `shabad`
        // handler and treat it accordingly. You can have as many message handlers
        // as you want but you should name them differently so you know where
        // each message came from.
        let jsSource = "window.webkit.messageHandlers.shabad.postMessage(Drupal.settings.hukam.shabad_lines.gurmukhi)"

        // Inject the script, to be executed after the page finishes loading
        let script = WKUserScript(source: jsSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

        // 
        let contentController = WKUserContentController()

        // Define the `shabad` message handler
        contentController.add(self, name: "shabad")

        // Add the script to the `WKWebView`. The script will executed every time
        // you load a webpage, even if it's not sikhnet.com
        contentController.addUserScript(script)

        // Finally, we can build a web view with the everything we want
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    }
}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {  
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        // We received a message from Javascript! Check its name and process the
        // message's body
        if message.name == "shabad", let lines = message.body as? [String] {
            // Now you have your 8 lines of shabad
            print(lines)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly appreciate how thorough your answer was because I had not yet dealt with WebKit in this way yet and wouldn't know what to google. I've also posted about this a total of 4 times now on various forums and this is the most simple solution so far as everyone else directly me to regex. I do have a question - Is there a way to speed up the loading?

Comment: @bhealth not really. How fast the page load depends on a lot of factors: your internet connection speed, how big the page is, the load on the webserver, how far away you are from it, etc.. One way is to cache it ahead time so it's ready when the user needs it.